# Why does mysql allow a foreign key to refer a part of composite primary key?

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose I have two tables in mysql
1.Child(name,father_name)
2.Father(name,contact)

The table Father has a composite key (name,contact).Father_name in Child table references name in father . Thus a foreign key references a part of primary key.This is allowed by mysql.

However consider the following situation:

Table father has the following tuples:

```
(kishan,9906011111)
(kishan,9990601234)
```

Now suppose I insert a row in child

```
(xyz,kishan)
```

How would I know which kishan in the father table is the child xyz related to ?

This situation could have been avoided if mysql does not allow a foreign key to refer a part of the primary key .

Please answer what's the benefit of this scheme allowed by mysql ?

Comment: Because it is possible that a *foreign* key maps to a **list** of values.

Answer (score 0):

This is a peculiarity of MySQL.  In my opinion, foreign keys should only be to unique keys or primary keys.  There should not be a mapping to "sets" of values using a foreign key relationship.

Clearly, the designers of MySQL disagree (both with me and other database implementors).  They allow foreign key relationships to any columns that are indexed -- in MySQL parlance, are defined as a "key".  If you have a composite primary key, then the initial column(s) are such a key.

To prevent problems and make your tables unambiguous and easy to use, I would recommend:

- All tables have an auto-incremented primary key.
- All foreign key relationships are *only* to primary keys (not to unique keys or other types of key).
- The primary key be named the singular of the entity followed by `id` (example:  `things` would have `thingId` as a primary key).
- The foreign key have the same name as the primary key (except when this is not possible because there are multiple foreign key relationships to the same table).